# Is reaching to next kalpa is common for some persons?

Tags: brahma, time

Some says after end of kalpa everything vanishes and Brahma goes to sleep for one kalpa. During his sleep, there is no existence of life left. And after one kalpa, Brahma wakes up and creates everything from beginning. So life started again by Brahma after his sleep. I also believes the same.

I know that Dhruv got boon from Lord Vishnu that he will be safe from mahaa pralaya at the end of kalpa but what about others? There are few examples I know who reached to the next kalpa well and fine. Here are few examples..

- Tarakasura: He was present at time of Sati. And when on next kalpa
  Pravati was born, he was present that time also. He died when
  Parvati's son Kartikeya killed him. So he live for more than one
  kalpa.
- Ganga: She was also present since Sati's time and till now she is
  well and fine. She was one more survivor.
- Prajapati (Sati's father): He was also one more person who also
  reached to the next kalpa with his wife.
- Narada: Who was present in every story, no matter the story is of
  which kalpa.

And there are many more examples can be found. Apart from those examples which are mentioned in any Purana, there must be many more which are unheard/unwritten.

**Point to notice in above examples**

In above examples, it is not like that those were created again by Brahma after his sleep. For examples: Ganga, Prajapati, Tarakasura etc are those who knew about previous kalpa's incidents because they were present that time. So they all reached to next kalpa without loosing their memories. Same as we reach in next year and remembers all about what we did, think and experienced in past year. So they were not created again.

**Here is my question**

If Brahma goes to sleep after one kalpa then how they all (above mentioned examples) lived without Brahma for one kalpa. Or may be all creation also goes in deep sleep with Brahma. Just like Brahma pressed pause button to stop a movie And when Brahma wakes up then he just resume movie instead of starting from begining. Because Sati's story (with all characters ex. Tadkasura, Prajapati, Ganga etc.) continued in next Kalpa. It's not like that Sati again commit suicide but instead Parvati born in next Kalpa and Tadkasura changed his target from Sati to Parvati in next kalpa.

So what's the real truth about kalpantara? Also on what reasons a person can survive to the next kalpa with all his/her experience of previous kalpa?

Comment: You have some misunderstandings here. Only 3 lokas are destroyed at end of Kalpa..

Comment: @thedestroyer Okay, then those three lokas must be patala loka, bhooloka and devaloka(perhaps). Tadkasura lived in Patala loka. Then how he survived? And Daksha and his wife also used to live in bhooloka, and still entered in next kalpa.

Comment: @thedestroyer And also, it is said that after end of kalpa, Brahma goes to sleep for one whole kalpa. Then what other does who are not sleeping like Brahma and lives in different lokas than 3 lokas who use to destroy?

Comment: Narada moved from last kalpa to this kalpa . But he didnt had current spiritual form in previous kalpas.I believe prajapati is a position name rather than actual person

Comment: @sysinit I know prajapati is position But I am talking about not position but I am talking about Prajapati Daksha who was Sati's father. On next Kalpa when Parvati born then Daksha met parvati. And after marriage  of Shiva and Parvati, Daksha met both and apologize from Shiva of his deeds. Then Shiva pleased with his prayer and Shiva convert his got head into a human head same as before. That's why I said Daksha (Sati's father) entered in next kalpa.

Comment: @sysinit And what do you mean by _" he didnt had current spiritual form in previous kalpas"_?

Comment: @Rishabh I didnt know the about the whole story about Daksha. Thanks for letting me know. But souls who have not achieved liberation move from kalpa to kalpa.  For Example all 5 pandavas were Indras in previous kalpas. So they again reborn this kalpa as devas without indrahood. Also You should include kaka bhusundi , who I believe existing in the same form from MANY kalpas

Comment: Narada was gandharva in previous kalpa and then became shudra due to a curse. Then he achieved current spiritual form , and moved to new kalpa.

Comment: Whatever gets destroyed or goes to sleep is within you. If you exist the world exist. Converting perception to reality creates more perceptions than reality.

Answer (score 1):

Krishna says in Gita 9.7-8 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> At the end of a cycle all beings, O son of Kunti, enter into My Prakriti, and at the beginning of a cycle I generate them again.
>
> Controlling My own Prakriti, I send forth, again and again, all this multitude of beings, helpless under the sway of maya.

In one of the Puranas, Vishnu in his Boar Incarnation says to the goddess "Every time I carry you this way..." When a cycle repeats, all the material beings of that previous cycle go through their same actions, all the events reoccur. The jivas in those new beings are, however, different jivas from the previous cycle.

Comment: This is I already know. And it's not even answering my question. I mentioned in my answer in first paragraph that _" I also believes the same."_

Comment: _"all the material beings of that previous cycle go through their same actions"_ You are talking about which cycle? You mean every kalpa? If yes, then Sati didn't repeat. Instead Parvati present in this kalpa. And all examples that i shown in my question didn't repeat either.

Comment: if you agree that Rama and Krishna are born in previous kalpa, Then its fair assumption that all the events are repetative, but jivas different may be having the same name.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for Markandeya and he did see thousands of ages pass away and also worships Brahma during the dissolution of the universe.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03187.htm

> "Then the virtuous king Yudhishthira in all humility again enquired of the illustrious Markandeya, saying, 'O great Muni, thou hast seen many thousands of ages pass away. In this world there is none so longlived as thou! O best of those that have attained the knowledge of Supreme Spirit, there is none equal to thee in years except the great-minded Brahma living in the most exalted place. Thou, O Brahmana, worshippest Brahma at the time of the great dissolution of the universe, when this world is without sky and without the gods and Danavas. And when that cataclysm ceaseth and the Grandsire awaketh, **thou alone, O regenerate Rishi, beholdest Brahma duly re-create the four orders of beings after having filled the cardinal points with air and consigned the waters to their proper place.**

> Many a time in days of yore hast thou beheld the Supreme Creator of the universe with eyes of spiritual abstraction and renunciation, having first opened thy pure and lotus-like heart--the only place where the multiform Vishnu of universal knowledge may be seen! It is for this, O learned Rishi, by the grace of God neither all-destroying Death, nor dotage that causeth the decay of the body, hath any power over thee! When neither the sun, nor the moon, nor fire, nor earth, nor air, nor sky remains, when all the world being destroyed looketh like one vast ocean, when the Gods and Asuras and the great Uragas are annihilated, and when the great-minded Brahma, the Lord of all creatures, taking his seat on a lotus flower, sleepeth there, then thou alone remainest to worship him! And, O best of Brahman as thou hast seen all this that occurred before, with thy own eyes. **And thou alone hast witnessed many things by the senses, and never in all the worlds hath there been any thing unknown to thee!** Therefore do I long to hear any discourse explaining the causes of things!"